# Mysql giving me a syntax error when trying to create a table. I can't find where this error is

Tags: mysql

So when trying to create this table the console returns a syntax error that I just can't figure out.

```
CREATE TABLE Photobook( PhotoID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                        filepath VARCHAR(30) NULL, desc VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL);
```

this returns

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'desc VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL)' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) `DESC` with backticks:

> Nonreserved keywords are permitted as identifiers without quoting.
>   **Reserved words are permitted as identifiers if you quote them.**

```
CREATE TABLE Photobook( PhotoID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                       filepath VARCHAR(30) NULL, `desc` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL);
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95987)**</kbd>

or change column name to `description`

Comment: Yeah, I realized that just a moment after posting the question. Thanks though!